# Problems with @INC when updating Perl form 5.10 to 5.18 on Centos

Tags: centos, perl, path

I am on Centos 6 (as root) with Perl 5.10, also with a lot of modules installed (using yum and CPAN). I've tried to upgrade Perl to 5.18 and now have some problems with @INC.

I receive messages that some modules are not able in @INC, I've solved some of them reinstalling them from yum, but some of them are still unavaliable.

Please show the best way to add my earlier installed modules to @INC (I've already read a lot forums about this problem, and solutions like writing use lib or adding old modules path in bash are not very good as for me)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED:

Am I able to downgrade to 5.10 and if yes then will my old modules work? Or the only right way is to reinstall my system?

Comment: It is usually a *really bad idea* to try to replace something like a system Perl installation. If you really need a  newer Perl, create your own environment with something like [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) instead.

Comment: Now I understand:) But got what I've got:) The current behavior of my Perl has become strange, because f.e. some of my scripts work fine (using DBD::mysql), but some of them can't find this DBD::mysql

Comment: am I able to downgrade to 5.10 and if yes then will my old modules work?

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade?

Comment: I can't remember exactly because I've upgraded it two weeks ago and found problems only now. But as I remember and if I'm not mistaken I've did it with yum.

Comment: or I was trying to install a module from base modules of 5.18

Comment: HOw did you try the upgrade? what's the output of: 
"yum list installed perl"? 
of "which perl"? 
of "perl -V" ? 
what are the problems you have (command - expected result - actual result)?

Comment: As I remember I wanted to Install File::Find on Perl 5.10.2 from CPAN. CPAN asked would I like to upgrade perl to 5.18, because File::Find is a core module of 5.18. And I thought why not?!:)

Comment: perlbrew helped